# Tautological bundle on $\mathbb P^n$ is topologically trivial over the complement of a hypersurface.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

I'm asking this because I am confused about the first paragraph of section 1.1 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7229.pdf. In particular, I don't see why the $\mathbb C^*$-bundle $\Pi_{d,n}\setminus\Sigma_{d,n}\to N_{d,n}$ is trivial. Is this obvious? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The restriction of the tautological bundle ${\mathcal O}(-1)$ to the complement of a hypersurface $X \subset {\mathbb P}^n$ of degree $d > 1$ is NOT trivial. In fact, it is a generator of ${\mathrm{Pic}}({\mathbb P}^n \setminus X) \cong {\mathbb Z}/d{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: You're the second person to mention this exact thing to me today. I guess Vassiliev is wrong?

Comment: @HarryReed: Couldn't you misunderstand what he was saying?

Comment: Could be. He just says the total space $\Pi_{d,n}\setminus\Sigma_{d,n}$ is diffeomorphic to the product $N_{d,n}\times\Bbb C^*$, but they may not be as fiber bundles over $N_{d,n}$; but I don't see any other obvious map $\Pi_{d,n}\setminus\Sigma_{d,n}\to N_{d,n}$. Do you see something I don't?

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb P^n$ is the quotient of $\Bbb A^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ by the $\Bbb G_m$ action given by rescaling the coordinates. Restricting to the complement of a hypersurface $V(f)=H\subset \Bbb P^n$, we see that the pre-image under the quotient map is also affine (as it is $D(f)$ where $f$ is considered as a polynomial on $\Bbb A^{n+1}$). Since everything in sight is affine, one may inspect coordinate rings to see that $k[D(f)]\cong k[\Bbb P^n\setminus H]\otimes k[x,x^{-1}]$ and then the product description is clear.

To see this description of the coordinate rings, one may reduce to the case of $f=x_0$ by the embedding of $\Bbb P^n \subset \Bbb P^{N}$ given by $\mathcal{O}(d)$ and a linear change of coordinates, and then it ought to be relatively clear.

Comment: That $\mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\cong (\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb P^n$ is the only part I'm having trouble with. I'm pretty sure this particular isomorphism isn't even true. But Vassiliev's paper makes it sound like it is true after restricting this bundle to the complement of any hypersurface.

Comment: Oof, you're right. I got sloppy. Edits forthcoming.

Comment: What's the embedding $\Bbb P^n\subset\Bbb P^N$ given by $\mathcal O(d)$? Is this the Veronese embedding?

Comment: Yes, those are the same thing.